# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\\mysite\\settings'

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have read the previous questions and answers here, and tried the suggested solutions, however still getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '...\mysite\settings'

The project is DosV3Master with a folder under it and the typical files under mysite, asgi.py, settings.py, wsgi.py and so forth.

the venv folder is under the DosV3Master as is manage.py

When I run "python manage.py check" I get...

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master> python manage.py check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\check.py", line 76, in handle
    self.check(
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\templates.py", line 39, in check_string_if_invalid_is_string
    for conf in settings.TEMPLATES:
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup     
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__  
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\viter\\DoseV3Master\\mysite\\settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 425, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 84, in close_all
    for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 76, in all     
    return [
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__    return iter(self.settings)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__ 
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 102, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 89, in _setup     
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 217, in __init__  
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\viter\\DoseV3Master\\mysite\\settings'
(venv
```

The other questions and answers here suggested changes to wsgi.py which I incorporated as follows...

```
"""
WSGI config for mysite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
import sys
# import logging
# logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# logger.info("Now logging in wsgi")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = 'C:\\Users\\viter\\DoseV3Master\\'
#if path not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(path)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)

print("*********>", sys.path)

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I did the "python manage.py check" after adding the print statement to see what the sys.path was... I didn't find it in the terminal, so I must presume the wsgi.py is not executing and is the source of the problem.

So the question is why isn't the wsgi.py getting called?

I hope I can get wsgi.py running and can then debug.

as a side note, Dosv3Master is in the PYTHONPATH environment variable as I set that in the activate.ps1

```
# Add the venv to the PATH
Copy-Item -Path Env:PATH -Destination Env:_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
$Env:PATH = "$VenvExecDir$([System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator)$Env:PATH"

$Env:PYTHONPATH = "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\"

$Env:DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = "C:\Users\viter\DoseV3Master\mysite\settings.py"
```

Comment: Does `C:\\Users\\viter\\DoseV3Master\\mysite\\settings.py` exists ? if no, `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')` should point to an existing module (that contains your settings)

Comment: Yes it exists under mysite